# Disable editing of iframe

Tags: javascript, php, css, iframe, thumbnails

I wanted a "preview" thumbnail of every form I created. But I wanted that users can't edit the iframe on the thumbnail (somewhat it will just appear like an image)

this is my preview code

```
<p>Thumbnails</p>
<div id="wrap">
<iframe id="frame" src="<?php echo site_url('form/testing'); ?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this? CSS or javascript?

Answer (score 2):

what I understand from your question is you want to disable your form which is inside in an Iframe. you can do it.
 1. **you can place a full size div over your form so nobody can direcly access your form with css over your form**  [check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv8vT/)

(you can place the same div over your ifrmae tag )
CSS of div is

```
layer
{
opacity: 0.01;
}
```

1. you can disable user input and user select
   using css

> body {
>
> -webkit-user-select:none;   -moz-user-input: disabled; 
>   -webkit-user-input:disabled; }

using jquery

```
jQuery("input").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```